# Getting a notification from an object with a date property

Tags: ios, core-data, notifications, push-notification

I am working on a project that manages events. I will like to get a notification for when the date property of an event object is almost elapsed, say an hour before or 15 minutes before. Then use the notification centre to post it.

I am managing the events using coreData and I get the objects from the fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects into an array.

I am wondering if I can get a notification when the date of event in the array is due.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Other than checking your array over and over, I don't see a good way to do that. Why not just set a notification for each event in the array?

Comment: Sorry, I am still new in iOS, I don't understand what you mean by setting a notification for each event in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // using calendar to get current date and time in correct format
NSDateComponents *startDate = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit |
                                                    NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                    NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                                    NSHourCalendarUnit |
                                                    NSMinuteCalendarUnit |
                                                    NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:[NSDate date]];

startDate.hour -= 1;

NSDateComponents *endDate = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit |
                               NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                               NSYearCalendarUnit |
                               NSHourCalendarUnit |
                               NSMinuteCalendarUnit |
                               NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                          fromDate:[NSDate date]];

endDate.hour += 1;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(someDate >= %@) AND (someDate <= %@)", [calendar dateFromComponents:startDate], [calendar dateFromComponents:endDate]];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:DBNAME];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

if (results.count > 1) {
    NSLog(@"results of dates only within the next one hour: %@", results);
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    notification.alertBody = @"found date";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
} else {
    NSLog(@"no dates in db");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to iOS dev, Is there a way to do this in a timely manner and in a background thread, so that even if the app is not open it still works

Comment: look into UIApplicationDelegate, there a method called application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler

Comment: how do you get a managed object from another class and pass it to the app delegate. I tried Class *evc = [[Class alloc] init] then [evc useDocument] which opens the ManagedObject in a completions handler ([document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){if(success){self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;} else NSLog(@"couldn't open file");}];) then evc.managedObjectContext. it returns the nil entities.

Comment: I assume your core data functionally are in App delegate, AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; then have a method in there that will return the managed contexts or a property